How much of an advantage is it to play 2v1?
In sports with doubles & singles formats (like tennis/table tennis/badminton), how much of an advantage is it to play 2v1? We can assume the side with 2 plays with doubles rules - so e.g. they use the outer lines instead of the inner ones - while the side with 1 uses the singles rules.
I'm interested in answers of the form "the top 1 singles player in the world can beat the top 200 doubles pair in the world" or "the top 1 singles player in the world can beat the top 1 doubles pair on the senior circuit".

I am not aware of this ever happening in professional sports, so I don't see how this question can be answered.

@pacoverflow My guess is this is hypothetical(?) In which case it's still not answerable :/
